# Does English have a word that only means "to create a social bond"?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

Is there a word in English that exclusively means something like "to create a social bond", and which *can't* also mean a physical linkage?

I'm looking for something that can be used in a sentence like "the two friends were [word]ed together by their shared experience", but not in a sentence like *"the planks of wood were [worded] together" or *"just let me [word] my shoelaces".

For context, I'm trying to figure out if there's a good (non-ambiguous!) equivalent for the Japanese word "tsunagaru". Common English translations of that involve "link", "connect", "bond", etc., but all of those English words seem to be broader than the Japanese word in question.

Comment: Even 'marry' has broadened usages in the construction domain.

Comment: I am writing up an answer, using 'bond' as a verb, however, that would mean "creation of an emotional connection"  like friendship, a special friendship of an almost family sort of way , not merely an "association" where they exchanged cards and cooperated on projects as their primary interaction.  Is it the emotional tie of friendship or the cooperative tie of shared aims ?  For example, George Washington, Thomas Jefferson and others were 'bound' together by their shared dream of a new form of government for the American Colonies, yet there the myth doesn't depict them as 'pals' necessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***Endear (to)***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/endear) comes very close, though it isn't automatically a two-way connection. From Dictionary.com:

> to make dear, esteemed, or beloved:
>   *He endeared himself to his friends with his gentle ways.*

For your example sentence, you would need to make the [endearment](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/endearment) reciprocal:

> The two friends were **endeared to one another** by their shared experience.

It is occasionally possible for an inanimate object to endear itself to someone (e.g., "the movie *ET* and its title character endeared themselves to a generation of children"), but it is pretty exclusively used for an emotional response. You wouldn't say that *"glue endeared glitter to the card" or anything like that.

Some actual examples of this usage:

> Nightly through the long months of summer did the lovers keep their tryste, parting only after each meeting more and more **endeared to one another**.
>   —["Waw-o-Naisa, or, The origin of the whippoorwill", *The American Monthly Magazine*, July, 1836](https://books.google.com/books?id=SHRBAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA78&ots=NXn7TO1xe6&dq=%22endeared%20to%20one%20another%22&pg=PA79#v=onepage&q=%22endeared%20to%20one%20another%22&f=false)

---

> Christine and I also share crazy similarities in our life stories which has made us particularly **endeared to one another**.
>   —[Unposed Blog, August, 2017](http://unposedphotographyblog.com/christine-kyle-elegant-iowa-country-wedding/)

---

> Men will become **endeared to each other** while they are fighting together in the trenches of struggle, and when Ian attended a course in Pretoria instructed by Andre Thorburn, not only was a big step taken in Ian’s knife making; but something else was forged: a friendship.
>   —[The Cutting Edge (custom knife website), ND](http://ianvanreenenknives.com/Welcome.html)

Comment: Ooh, now that's a good one, particularly with the (non-obvious) last example related to brothers-in-arms. "Endear (to)" functions roughly the same way as the foreign word I'm thinking of (so I can map grammar easily), and carries connotations of creating social closeness. I'll wait a bit before accepting, but "endear" will definitely be useful for explaining certain translations.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen **fraternise** [with] used for non-personal-relational usages like 'form a social bond [with]'.

[WordNet ... Farlex](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fraternise) has:

> **fraternise**:  socialise, socialize - take part in social activities; interact with others
>
> *He never socializes/fraternizes with his colleagues*
>
> *The old man hates to socialize/fraternize*

and

> **fraternise** - be on friendly terms with someone, as if with a 
>   brother, especially with an enemy

Comment: Fraternize has a connotation of not actually being very close friends, I think.  It's like "hang out with".

Comment: @Max Williams If we worry overmuch about any but the most prevailing connotations, we'll never use any words at all.

Comment: But surely worrying about the subtleties of language is what makes this site so enjoyable?  Besides, I think this is "prevailing".  Consider *"Did you use to fraternize with Jim?"* *"We did more than fraternize - he was my best man and the godfather to my children"*.  In other words, the question is asking about a degree of friendship stronger than that implied by simply fraternizing with someone.

Comment: If there were a causative+habitual form of "fraternize" in English, I reckon it'd be a pretty solid option. +1 because this is definitely still useful, though it doesn't quite fit without rewording sentences during translation, or applying some creative word-formation ("fraternalize", maybe?).

Comment: @MaxWilliams in my specific case, degree of closeness isn't as important as making sure that "just let me [fraternize/endear/etc.] my shoelaces" sounds so obviously nonsensical as to be absurd (not a made-up example; that's basically what I said, albeit not in English). But for the sake of general applicability and such, makes sense to raise that point.

Comment: @Max Williams OP asks 'Is there a word in English that exclusively means something like "to create a social bond"?' Are you saying that 'take part in social activities; interact with others'  does not address this?    And how's this for an assumption of closeness: 'In Pryce's case, she had to attend every one of Prince's 21 shows as part of her job ...  "You aren't there to fraternise," she says, "simply to make certain that they are shown to their table, made comfortable and that their needs are attended to." ... Just don't mistake getting on professionally for ...

Comment: becoming bosom buddies.' {[The Guardian, 2007](https://www.theguardian.com/money/2007/oct/22/workandcareers.officehours3)}? // If someone asked for a modern synonym for 'wonderful, splendid', not necessarily formal, would you object to 'wicked'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the OP has since (in the comments) specified that he didn't need it to imply close friendship, so I withdraw my objection on that ground.  My reading was based on the example *"the two friends were [word]ed together by their shared experience"* (for which fraternize is still unsuitable btw).

Comment: My point remains; saying "You mustn't ever say 'That's a wicked dress" ' because someone's maiden aunt somewhere might not take it as intended is over-prescribing.  'Fraternise' is _often_ used to mean 'become on friendly terms with', and the definitions given above license this.  WordNet doesn't add a caveat about usage (I'd expect one with 'wicked' = 'wonderful'), so I don't see why you give one unsupported by any authoritative reference.

Comment: Does it mean "to *be* on [...]", or "to *become* on [...]"? If the former ("to be"), it doesn't fit the same role, though the meaning is somewhat related. If the latter ("to become"), then cool, there's some dialect (evidently not mine) for which this works even without trying to create an ad hoc causative inflection.

Comment: @Ethan Kaminski The two definitions given by Farlex cover both the meeting together and the being on friendly terms aspects. Initial fraternisation means you can't yet be friends and thus implies that (for the second definition to hold) you become friends. 'Fraternising with the enemy' obviously has this thrust.

Answer (score 0):

I think **bonded** is totally unambiguous *in context*, "The two friends **bonded** over a shared experience" would never be interpreted as "The two friends where permanently attached together in a physical manner by adhesive, pressure or heat."

English is very context dependent, and in this context the meaning of 'Bonded' is **"emotionally or psychologically linked."**

Comment: Yes, but **bonded** is also used, very frequently, to mean _physically_ attached, which is what the OP is specifically trying to avoid. You seem to be saying that he shouldn't try to avoid that, but he is, and the other answers fit that requirement.

Comment: OP goes on to say they are looking for "a good (non-ambiguous!) equivalent for the Japanese word "tsunagaru"."  'Bonded is totally non-ambiguous if used in this context.

Comment: In a super-clear context, it may not be. But it absolutely is a word with both discrete meanings, and so by its very nature it has some ambiguity. The entire point of this post is to find a word that *doesn't* have both meanings -- the OP already knows about *bond* and other words that do have both meanings.

Comment: It fails in the first of the two anti-examples: you can definitely say "the planks were bonded together" (well, maybe "are"), which is the translation pitfall I'm trying to avoid. I could potentially edit the question to be clearer about wanting a word that's non-ambiguous, even when that word is devoid of context, if that would help.

Comment: @EthanKaminski Why the proscription against physical linking. Entirely out of context "The two people bonded" can only mean "The two people became friends". It has absolutely no connotation of physicality in that shortest of sentences.

Comment: That said, it takes some searching to find a dictionary thesaurus which recognizes a definition of 'bond' as 'getting closer emotionally': [Thesuarus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/bond) (look for alliance and association sections). [Google misses it entirely](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=bond+definition) and [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bond) only has a small entry. [Collins has it up top](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/bond)

Comment: @Mitch because "let me bond my shoelaces real quick" is intelligible (if stilted), whereas using "tsunagaru" in the equivalent Japanese sentence is completely nonsensical. I'm specifically aiming to capture that nonsensicality in English, especially since most dictionary translations of "tsunagaru" use English words which are polysemous between physical and social/metaphorical connections (and the foreign word there is most definitely not, based on the conversational difficulty I had!). Basically, I've got a translation scenario where I want to avoid a specific out-of-context misinterpretation

Comment: @EthanKaminski OK, I get it now. 1) very stilted to the point where I would maintain that it is just as much nonsense what you say tsungaru is in Japanese (I don't know Japanese at all). 2) that's pretty specific requirements, like translating poetry, and you probably can't expect all those criteria to be met in English, so expect a looser translation. 3) single words don't have a monopoly on communication; a couple of words may be OK.  'created a social _connection_'?

Comment: @Mitch 1) definitely stilted, but I think "let me endear my shoelaces real quick" is closer to what I accidentally said in Japanese. Plus, "can I say 'bond' with shoelaces? or not?" would probably be understood, right? 2) yeah, agreed that an exact match won't be found. I was actually expecting no good equivalent, so the fact that there *are* two potential candidates is pleasantly surprising. 3) a phrase might for my purposes, the key thing is the aspect of "definitely cannot be used as...". I'll have to think about how to describe that accurately for phrases.

Comment: @JeffUK I don't see where the OP is asking for a word that can be used without the context of it implying that it happened between people ?  Also,  I don't think it is regional or generation but maybe, if you mentioned two people "bonding" there would be absolutely no sexual inuendo to it (well if in person with air quotes or a smirk maybe) and it would also not me "united" or "teamed up" etc...  If their fates were intertwined without an emotional-tie it would be a different word "bound"